# RREFU proof: how is Vx zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

While looking at Linear Algebra book of David C. Lay, I've found that uniqueness of reduced row echelon form can be proved by assuming there are two RREFs of a matrix A and showing every single column of those RREFs, U and V, are same.

I understood that two diffrent RREFs of matrix A have same corresponding pivot columns, and the book says even other columns of two RREFs are same because, we can have a vector x, which makes Ux=0, then Vx=0.

I don't know why Ux=0 makes Vx=0.

Comment: Are U and V the RREF form matrices

Comment: Yes, I believe they are.

Comment: What page is this on in David C. Lay, I have the book on my shelf.

Comment: Appendix A shows the proof.

Comment: Oh, ok. I just read it. The crucial fact for the proof is that the $j'th$ column of $\vec{v}$ is 1, which forces the matrices to be the same. But any two row equivalent matrices have the same solutions to $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one associates to a matrix $A$ the linear homogeneous equation $A\cdot x=0$ where $x$ is an unknown column vector of the right size (the number of columns of $A$), the row operations are designed to transform a matrix into another matrix with an *equivalent* associated equation. So if $U$ is a RREF for $A$ (or indeed any matrix obtained from $A$ by row operations) then $U\cdot x=0$ is equivalent to $A\cdot x=0$. And then of course if $V$ is another such matrix, the equation $U\cdot x=0$ is equivalent to $V\cdot x=0$.

Comment: thanks for answering! now i understand why.